# Best way to copy weight from pretrained model to my newly defined model with skip branches in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I want to fine-tuning the existing state-of-the-art models on ImageNet for my own task. My model is adapted from vgg network and it has several branches connected to different convolution layer output, kind of like the following:
[image]

But the [definition of vgg model](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/vgg.py) in torchvision is not so straight forward. It is composed of a feature module and a classifier module, both of them are `nn.Sequential`, which makes it hard to make a branch from the output of  intermediate convolution layers. So right now, I manually define the new model layers by layers and do not use `nn.Sequential`, just like [this](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/mnist/main.py#L52).

But there is problem. Now the newly defined model do share same weight with the original vgg network in some of the layers, however, the layer names do not correspond any more. Of course I can manually find the correspondence between the weight of the old and new models and copy the weight directly. I think it is cumbersome. Is there a simpler way to do copy the weight from old model to the new model?

Comment: If I am understanding your problem correctly, you want to load weights from old structure of VGG to your newly structured VGG directly using something like `load_state_dict()`, right? It is not possible since you have many other branches in your new structure. You have to iterate over the parameters and load the weights as you described.

Comment: yes, the new model share some weight with the old model, so I want to fill these weight using the weight of original vgg model.